# HTML5 Canvas circle inside circle

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

Trying to build this using HTML5 Canvas, but not able to understand how to rotate the inner circles? Or is there any other 3rd party library to do this more easily.

```js
// CONSTANTS
const LAYER_3 = 3
const MAIN_RADIUS = 250

var context = document.getElementById('testCanvas').getContext('2d')

// draw a circle
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'orange'
context.arc(MAIN_RADIUS, MAIN_RADIUS, MAIN_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
context.fill()
for (i = 0; i < LAYER_3; i++) {
  const PARENT_RADIUS = (MAIN_RADIUS / 2)
  console.log(PARENT_RADIUS)
  context.beginPath();
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'
  context.fillStyle = 'blue'
  if (i == 0) {
    context.arc(PARENT_RADIUS, MAIN_RADIUS - (PARENT_RADIUS / 2), PARENT_RADIUS / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
  } else if (i == 1) {
    context.arc(PARENT_RADIUS, MAIN_RADIUS - (PARENT_RADIUS / 2), PARENT_RADIUS / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
  } else if (i == 2) {
    context.arc(PARENT_RADIUS, MAIN_RADIUS - (PARENT_RADIUS / 2), PARENT_RADIUS / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
  }
  context.closePath()
  context.fill()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is really simple in HTML5 Canvas, you should show some code of what you tried so far

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Sorry, I did not add my code as it was not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have not used the `context.rotate` so yes the circles are not going to rotate...
You might want to read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate

Here is an example using your code as a starting point

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const PARENT_RADIUS = 100
const CHILDREN_RADIUS = 40

// Move to the center of the canvas
context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
context.beginPath();
context.fillStyle = 'orange'
context.arc(0, 0, PARENT_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
context.fill()

// Draw the inner circles
context.fillStyle = 'blue'
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.rotate(2 * Math.PI / 3);
  context.arc(CHILDREN_RADIUS * 1.3, 0, CHILDREN_RADIUS, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  context.fill()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh Yes, thank you. So bad I missed the rotate.